# Salesforce Exposing sandbox metadata in another sandbox

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

Customer wants a way to expose sandbox metadata in their system.

So basically, they manage other salesforce orgs. They want the ability create a connection object to link their prod org to another sandbox.

Then linking that connection to another object which has a picklist.

The picklist will be say "Apex Class". when that is chosen, the connection should list all Apex Classes in the sandbox.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the Metada API from salesforce, there are some libraries that will help you I use [Jsforce](https://jsforce.github.io/document/#metadata-api). So basically you can create a connection to the sandbox on the production organization on the visual force page using plain javasccript and you could list any object from the sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew Fawcett has a written wonderful apex wrapper class for salesforce metadata api.

Please refer: https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

There is a "**Deploy to Salesforce**" button which you can click and it will deploy this whole codebase in your developer org easily.

Then, you can reference his classes from your apex code/VF code.
Try it out. You will like it a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is using the Tooling API. You can test it in the developer workbench https://workbench.developerforce.com/restExplorer.php.

For example, to get a list of all Apex Classes you would make a GET request to this path:

```
/services/data/v37.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+Name+FROM+ApexClass
```

Or to get a list of Workflow Rules:

```
/services/data/v37.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+Name+FROM+WorkflowRule
```

In Apex, you can just make an http request to those endpoints. The result would be in JSON format. You can deserialize it using the built in Apex JSON library.